# Bundle Scala-sbt module and UI together

Tags: scala, build, sbt, multi-module

I have a multi module project with SBT. The project structure is as below:

```
MyApp
    |--MyApp-api
    |--MyApp-ui
```

`MyApp-api` -> contains the scala module

`MyApp-ui`  -> contains the ui module (html/js/css etc)

I am using `SBT` for build. I am able to assemble MyApp-api module using `sbt-assembly`. UI module communicate with the api though REST calls. I want to bundle both api and ui modules together and then deploy in some server. How can I package both UI and API together using SBT(something like building a war file)? I do not want to put all the UI contents into resource folder of API. The reason is that I might need to deploy UI and API separately in the near future. 
Any help would be really appreciated.